# Null pointer exception when passing a list from Apex class to Trigger

Tags: apex

I am getting the error:

> 'System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object'.

Trigger code snippet:

```
List<Territory_Budget__c> tbErrorList = new List<Territory_Budget__c>();        
 tbErrorList=LBK_NL_Budget_Limit.budgetLimit(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
```

From the class, I am returning a list of `Territory_Budget__c` objects.

Thanx in advanced!!!

Comment: On which event you are running trigger?

Comment: We need more code.  It is likely that this error is occurring in the `budgetLimit()` method in the `LBK_NL_Budget_Limit` Class.  The error usually tells you the line of code that is causing the error.  That would be helpful information here.

Comment: You will also get an NPE on `Trigger.newMap.keySet()` if its a delete event because `newMap` will be null

Comment: The error is likely being thrown on `Trigger.newMap` and I suspect that this is in a `before insert` trigger where `newMap` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you have a null pointer (a variable which is null) and that you are trying to do something on it.

Assuming that the error is occurring on one of the two lines of code you've provided, I would suggest that you look at this statement

> LBK_NL_Budget_Limit.budgetLimit

Could LBK_NL_Budget_Limit be null?
try

```
if (LBK_NL_Budget_Limit != null) {
    tbErrorList=LBK_NL_Budget_Limit.budgetLimit(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Comment: I think `LBK_NL_Budget_Limit` is a class

Comment: Hmmm, makes sense... it would be useful to actually know what line of code was failing...

Comment: And I guess to confirm that budgetLimit is a static method of a class called LBK_NL_Budget_Limit and not an instance method of a class which is referred to by a variable LBK_NL_Budget_Limit... the latter would make sense if this is indeed the line which is failing

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at answering the question and say that the solution is to change the loop in your budgetLimit method to loop through a list instead of a set, and use Trigger.New instead of Trigger.NewMap.keySet() as the parameters when you call the method.